# Bound on L2-Norm of Probability Distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, function-spaces

I am working on a problem where I have continuous probability distributions $p$  over a bounded domain $D$, i.e., $\forall x$ $p(x) \geq 0$ and $\|p\|_1 = \int_D p(x) dx = 1$. However, I also want $p$ to have bounded function 2-norm, i.e., $\|p\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_D p(x)^2 dx} \leq c$ for some finite $c$. <s>Is there a name for such a class of distributions?</s> Edit: Assuming $p \in L^2$, can one bound $\|p\|_2$ with some other quantities involving $p$? I provide some examples in the following paragraph.

The trivial bound is $\|p\|_2 \leq \|p\|_\infty {\rm Vol}(D)$. I am looking for something better, if possible. It seems that exponential distributions with large-enough *spread* have low 2-norm. Also, for uniform distributions one can easily get $\|p\|_2$ as a function of the volume of the domain $D$. I am looking for any resources / references along this direction. Please help.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, I looked at the Plancherel Identity, and realize that $p \in L^2$ iff the characteristic function of the random variable $X$ having density $p$ is in $L^2$. However, I am looking for a simpler bound on $\|p\|_2$, or a condition on $p$ that is simpler than assuming the characteristic function is square integrable.

Comment: The distribution function $p$ is in $L^2$ if and only if the associated characteristic function is in $L^2$, this follows from Plancherel identity. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973129), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083508) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028910) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at Plancherel @StratosFair. I am looking for a simpler bound on $\|p\|_2$, or a simpler condition on $p$ than assuming the characteristic function is  in $L^2$. Edited question to reflect the same.